# R shiny: How to add RadioButton in a table?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to add a choice row at the bottom of table. I searched for some answers but it included many other functions it was hard for me to understand.

```
library(shiny)
c1 <-c("Time in free flow (mins)",
       "Time slowed down by other traffic (mins)",
       "Percentage of total time spent with other vehicles close behind",
       "Curviness",
       "Running costs",
       "Toll cost") 

c2 <- c('50','10','25%','Moderate','$12.00','$0.00')

c3 <- c('38','5','31%','extreame','$10.50','$3.00')

c4 <- c('62','8','19%','Almost straight','$9.00','$0.50')

c5 <- c('56','15','12%','Moderate','$13.50','$0.00')

t <- cbind(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)

ui <- fluidPage(

  tableOutput("faith")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$faith <- renderTable({t}, type = "html", bordered = TRUE, striped = TRUE, align = "c")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I updated some code based on the comments, but still don't know how to get the select value

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


c1 <-c("Time in free flow (mins)",
       "Time slowed down by other traffic (mins)",
       "Percentage of total time spent with other vehicles close behind",
       "Curviness",
       "Running costs",
       "Toll cost") 

c2 <- c('50','10','25%','Moderate','$12.00','$0.00')

c3 <- c('38','5','31%','extreame','$10.50','$3.00')

c4 <- c('62','8','19%','Almost straight','$9.00','$0.50')

c5 <- c('56','15','12%','Moderate','$13.50','$0.00')

t <- cbind(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)
tm <- c('<input type="radio" name="Dec" value="1"/>',
        '<input type="radio" name="Dec" value="2"/>',
        '<input type="radio" name="Dec" value="3"/>',
        '<input type="radio" name="Dec" value="4"/>',
        '<input type="radio" name="Dec" value="5"/>')

tmm <- rbind(t,tm)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Radio buttons in a table',
    DT::dataTableOutput('foo'),
    verbatimTextOutput('sel')
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {



    output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
      tmm, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
      options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
      callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
          var $this = $(this.node());
          $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
          $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
        });
        Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
        Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    )
    output$sel = renderPrint({
      str(sapply('Dec', function(i) input[[i]]))
    })
  }
)
```

Any suggestion is welcome.
This is what I try to do. Add a single choice row.
[image: This is what I try to do.]

Comment: Please see the [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/011-radio.html).

Comment: Sorry, I am not understand the JS code part. I already update the code accroding the decumentation. But how can I get the select value?@ismirsehregal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it!
But still don't know how to submit the select value though observeEvent.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(googlesheets4)

c1 <-c("Time in free flow (mins)",
       "Time slowed down by other traffic (mins)",
       "Percentage of total time spent with other vehicles close behind",
       "Curviness",
       "Running costs",
       "Toll cost") 

c2 <- c('50','10','25%','Moderate','$12.00','$0.00')

c3 <- c('38','5','31%','extreame','$10.50','$3.00')

c4 <- c('62','8','19%','Almost straight','$9.00','$0.50')

c5 <- c('56','15','12%','Moderate','$13.50','$0.00')

t <- cbind(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    title = 'Radio buttons in a table',
    DT::dataTableOutput('foo'),
    
    tt <- textOutput('sel')
    textOutput('sel'),
    actionButton("submit", "submit")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    m = matrix(
      as.character(1:4), nrow = 1, ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE,
      dimnames = list(' ', LETTERS[1:4])
    )
    for (i in seq_len(nrow(m))) {
      m[i, ] = sprintf(
        '<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s"/>',
        ' ', m[i, ]
      )
    }
    m <- cbind('Chioce',m)
    
    m<-rbind(t,m) 
    output$foo = DT::renderDataTable(
      m, escape = FALSE, selection = 'none', server = FALSE,
      options = list(dom = 't', paging = FALSE, ordering = FALSE),
      callback = JS("table.rows().every(function(i, tab, row) {
          var $this = $(this.node());
          $this.attr('id', this.data()[0]);
          $this.addClass('shiny-input-radiogroup');
        });
        Shiny.unbindAll(table.table().node());
        Shiny.bindAll(table.table().node());")
    )
    output$sel = renderPrint({
      str(sapply(' ', function(i) input[[i]]))
    })
    
    
    
    observeEvent(input$submit,{
      
    })}
  
  
  
)
```